# How to mix imperfections bitmap with emissive color?

Tags: materials, shaders, emission

I'm trying to create an emissive store sign for Cycles that applies imperfections from a bitmap (I want the sign to appear weathered and distressed).

Working with a Principled BSDF, I know how to apply imperfections to the Base Color output by linking the imperfections bitmap to the BSDF's Roughness input, but this does not appear to affect the Emission output. Try as I may, I cannot figure out how to mix imperfections into the Emission color output (short of creating a color bitmap with imperfections already applied). Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.3.0, Windows 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variability in roughness affects the surface in subtle ways. Since emission overlays color on top of the base, it makes the effect even more subtle. So what you want to do is either decrease the emission strength (and perhaps also plug the emission color to the the base color, to at least partially neutralize brightness decrease), or crank up things that make the roughness more prominent (changing to metallic or increasing specularity).

Or perhaps you just don't know that you can mix colors yourself, and so all you need is a **Mix RGB** node connected to the emission:

[image]